# Special setter method in association of postgres is taking too long

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, backend

```
Lists.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: "creator_id", as: "creator" });    
let payload= { ...newTask };   
res = await Lists.create(payload);    
await res.setCreator(userId);
```

Generated Queries:
Executing (default):
INSERT INTO "public"."lists" ("id","title","date","status","t_shirt_size","priority","category","in_focus","created_at","updated_at","project_id") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11) RETURNING "id","title","description","date","status","meta","t_shirt_size","priority","additional_comment","category","bug_source","in_focus","created_at","updated_at","project_id","goal_id","category_id","type_id","creator_id","owner_id","reviewer_id","parent_id","story_id","department_id","marketing_tasks_id";

Executing (default): UPDATE "public"."lists" SET "creator_id"=$1,"updated_at"=$2 WHERE "id" = $3

here after the creation of a row, the setCreator function takes 20-30s to execute. Why is it so slow? how to optimize it?

I tried using raw queries to update the row.

tried directly inserting the creator_id in the payload but it still is slow.

Comment: Could you show both generated SQL queries in the post?

Comment: @Anatoly I did now please check

Comment: How many records do you have in `lists` table? What indexes do you have in it?

Comment: 366 records in the list table and an index for id @Anatoly

Comment: It seems something is odd with DB. 366 records are way too small amount to make such delay (and especially taking into account the index). It should work almost immediately if it is a local DB or anywhere near the service you run.

Comment: @Anatoly it is not a local DB. it is a development DB

Comment: Does SELECT with the condition by id also take that much time?

Comment: @Anatoly no, it takes time only when I try to insert creator_id or update it

Comment: What about a foreign key definition in DB? How many records in Users table?

Comment: @Anatoly 128 records in Users table

Comment: Could it be that you have any hooks for Sequelize models?

Comment: Yes, there are afterCreate, beforeBulkUpdate hooks @Anatoly

Comment: Could you try `setCreator` without them?